# Calculate a SoC (battery) forecast with Flux / Grafana based on a known pv power generation and ac consumption

Tags: influxql

I need some help with forecasting my solar battery state of charge in Flux.

General information:
I have a pv solar system with battery, and all metrics are accessible via iobroker >> modbus >> influxdb.
So I know the current state of charge, as well as the historical state of chage on a hourly basis.
Also I use "pvforecast" to predict pv power generation on a hourly basis.

What I want to do:
Say, I know the current state of charge (= capacity, the kilowatt hours stored in my battery).
And I also know the forecasted pv power generation per hour (pvforecast) , which will increase my battery soc - until it reaches maximum capacity of 11.2kWh.
From historical data I also calculated the average power consumption (ac) per hour.

Using these information I want to calculate the battery soc for each (future) hour of the day:

capacity + pvforecast - ac

This shold produce something like this:
[Grafana Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNRlt.png)

What I'm struggling with is that the result (capacity) of one row ( = hour) is the basis to calculate the next row ( = hour).
And also there is a maximum soc at 11.2kWh.

[Grafana Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPFO2.png)

So the calculated capacity for - say - 10:00 AM would be the capacity to start with in the 11:00 AM row. And so on...

How can I calculate this?
Help is much appreciated!

Greetings, Michael

I could not find anything helpful in the Flux documentation.
And ChatGPT suggested approaches that simply never existed in FluxQL. ;-)